# Refactor this code for ARC compliance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

how would I refactor this code for ARC:

```
- (UIGestureRecognizer *)createTapRecognizerWithSelector:(SEL)selector {
    return [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:selector] autorelease];
}
```

thanks for any help

Comment: As far as I know ARC takes over control of all reference issues. So you can remove your autorelease message (and retain, release, dealloc too). Or am I misunderstanding your intention?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the autorelease statement and rename the method:

```
- (UIGestureRecognizer *)newTapRecognizerWithSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    return [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:selector];
}
```

Comment: any idea why I'd get the error message "Use of undeclared declared identifier 'UITapRecognizer' ? thanks again

Comment: Changing the name to start with *new* implicitly changes the method from [returning unretained](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#objects.operands.other-returns) to [returning retained](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#objects.operands.retained-returns). That may be okay, but it's different from the original method.

Comment: @Caleb, Indeed - the distinction is notable. Whereas 'create' did return an autoreleased object, the 'new' method, refactored for ARC, returns an owned reference to the caller, which ARC assumes responsibility for releasing. To my thinking, this more accurately expresses the behavior of the code. To continue to use 'create' would be to continue to imply an autoreleased object is being returned, when, under ARC, this is no longer explicitly the case.

Comment: @isaac With ARC you shouldn't have to worry about whether the returned object is autoreleased or not -- ARC should take care of it either way. I'd probably call the method `-tapRecognizerWithSelector:`, but to some degree it's just a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `autorelease`. That should do it

Hope this helps you.